# How to implement HSTS in my website

Tags: php, http, curl, https, hsts

I've a website (domain from godaddy and hosted in hostgator). As I updated the certificates, manually, I can redirect my site to https, but it is always going to http from google search. After searching online, I got to know that Considering `Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15768000` as result of `curl -i -L` on target domain will work for my need as it will force a browser to open the website in https. But I'm confused about how to implement this to my website.

Can anyone help me on this ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Not sure this is right for Stack Overflow. Then again it covers so many topics that it doesn't fit nicely in any other Stack Exchange site either. So anyway will attempt to answer.

**Redirects.**

What do you mean "I can redirect my site to https"? You should redirect your site to https now you've gone through the hassle of setting this up so are you doing it? Or are you able to access both http and https? If so find out how to force https even if the user sets up http.

This is set up with a redirect rule on your web server. Not sure whether you have direct access to your config (e.g. .htaccess file if using Apache) or require your host provider to set this up for you.

**Google search**

Regarding Google Search, once you have the redirect set up, it will take some time for Google to recognise this and update the links in their search index to show the https version of the pages.

Saying that there are ways you can tell Google about this to hurry up the process:

- Do you force a redirect to https? If not Google will decide which site to show (http or https) based on a number of factors.
- Do you have a site map and have you updated those links to https?
- Do you have a `rel="canonical"` setting in the HTML of any of your pages and is it set to the https version? This tells Google which is the real version of the page if, for example, you allow both http and https versions of the page (not recommended).
- Have you registered the https version of your site with Google Search Console? If so are there any errors in there? You can also kick off a re-index request in here.
- Have you set all internal links to be https or, better yet, relative links.
- Can you update any external links to be https instead of http.

**HTTP Strict Transport Security (HSTS)**

This is an advanced topic so really wouldn't recommend it until you understand it more. Basically it's a HTTP Header you send back with your webpage over https to tell web browsers "hey I'm an https-only site. From now on, automatically translate any http requests to https automatically **before** you even send them to me".

It is a good security addition **on top of** redirects but crucially it **does not replace** the need for redirects. Redirects need to be in place first to send it to https, at which point your web server can send the HSTS HTTP Header (and which the browser will cache so it knows to change to HTTPS next time).

To set it up you send a HTTP Header like this (but only over https requests).

```
Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=16070400"
```

This can be setup in your webserver, or in your php files or any other way you can send HTTP Headers.

Be aware that this we'll prevent your site being available over http, so if you decide to turn off https for whatever reason, then you've basically blocked you're site for up to the max-age time for any browsers that have cached that setting.

For more information on HSTS see here:
[301 Redirect and HSTS in .htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37767031/301-redirect-and-hsts-in-htaccess)

But I really don't think that's what you are looking for here. It tells web browsers (like Google Chrome) to force https and is nothing to do with search engines (like Google Search) as, at present, they ignore this Header.

Comment: Thanks - great answer and deserved to be marked as such

Comment: It's not "nothing to do with search engines". Google explicitly takes into account `http`/`s` support in their page rankings: https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2014/08/https-as-ranking-signal.html. If the website in question is "always going to HTTP from Google Search", then aside from the slight security concerns, it will also have a small negative impact on its SEO.

Comment: I said HSTS has nothing to do with search engines - not that HTTPS has nothing to do with search engines.