# Next JS Google Cloud App Engine SSL/HTTPS

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, next.js

I have a simple serverless Next JS app running in Google Cloud App Engine. I have an SSL cert configured, and I can see it works by visiting my URL. I.e. https://example.com/ however, if I visit http://example.com/ it does not auto redirect to the HTTPS enabled version of my site.

app.yaml -

```
runtime: nodejs
env: flex

# This sample incurs costs to run on the App Engine flexible environment.
# The settings below are to reduce costs during testing and are not appropriate
# for production use. For more information, see:
# https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml
service: auto
handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: auto
  secure: always
manual_scaling:
  instances: 1
resources:
  cpu: 1
  memory_gb: 0.5
  disk_size_gb: 10
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to implement the code to redirect or force HTTPS over HTTP this is mentioned on [the docs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/securing-custom-domains-with-ssl#using_strict-transport-security_headers) as follows

> For security reasons, all applications should encourage clients to use https connections. You can use the Strict-Transport-Security header to instruct the browser to prefer https over http.

Take a look at [this cheat sheet](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security_Cheat_Sheet.html) on the Strict-Transport-Security header to understand better what it is and how does it work. also take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45745801/5387454) from another Question it gives a good explanation.

Finally here is [the guide](https://support.cloudways.com/enable-hsts-policy/) on how to implement it