# Unable to see strict-transport-security parameter in HEADERS response in postman?

Tags: scala, amazon-web-services, ssl, nginx, hsts

I am Trying to Implement HSTS in play framework typesafe server using scala code.

I have updated the application.config file with below line :

```
 play.filters.enabled += "play.filters.headers.SecurityHeadersFilter"
 play.filters.headers.frameOptions = "DENY"
 play.filters.https.strictTransportSecurity="max-age=31536000;includeSubDomains; preload"
```

So, After adding this when I execute the URL: https://www.mywebsite.com in postman, in headers column I expect to see:

```
 content-length: 85
 content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
 request-time: 2
 x-frame-options: DENY
 strict-transport-security: max-age=15552000; preload
```

These content length, type and time are already coming, but these strict transport parameters are not reflected in headers response in postman post the code changes in the config file.

Apart from the above line of code I even added these line of code in app.config:

```
    https {
     strictTransportSecurity = "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains"
     redirectStatusCode = 308
      }
```

But these changes is also having no effect on response heaaders.

To be brief, what I expect is if I used curl in git bash for my site, I will see similar to what I see for Facebook:

```
 curl --head https://www.facebook.com
 x-frame-options: DENY
 strict-transport-security: max-age=15552000; preload
 x-content-type-options: nosniff
```

The same way for my URL when I put https://www.mywebsite.com I need to see:

```
     strict-transport-security: max-age=15552000; preload
```

in headers response column but I do not see this.

Can anyone please point out where I am going wrong with this. I am new to HSTS and Scala and security task.

I tried to add in App.config file

```
  play.filters.enabled += "play.filters.https.RedirectHttpsFilter"
  play.filters.https.redirectEnabled = true
  play.filters.enabled += "play.filters.headers.SecurityHeadersFilter"
  play.http.forwarded.trustedProxies=["0.0.0.0/0", "::/0"]
  play.filters.https.strictTransportSecurity = "max-age=31536000; 
  includeSubDomains; preload"
  play.filters.https.redirectStatusCode = 301
```

But not coming in headers response. Where else should I change the code in playframework to display it in headers.

Comment: @users can anyone pls help me on this

Comment: Your question needs improvement. Your code block is badly formatted, includes newlines that may or may not be in the real config, includes irrelevant info(the whole location piece), includes two different Strict-Transport-Security headers (one with a semi-colon - one without) then says you only see some unformated postman output without saying what you did to get that, then similar unrelated, unformatted curl output. Your basic syntax for add_header looks about right but I've no idea of your set up, why this is related to Scala or AWS, or why you think this is not working, so can't help.

Comment: @BarryPollard, Thanks for your comments.!!! Now I have edited the issue I am facing can you please help me out here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know Scala or playframework, but from a quick Google, it seems to me like strictTransportSecurity is not part of [SecurityHeadersFilter](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/SecurityHeaders), but [part of RedirectHttpsFilter](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/RedirectHttpsFilter).

So do you need to include this filter?

```
play.filters.enabled += play.filters.https.RedirectHttpsFilter
```

And note also this comment:

> By default, the redirect only happens in Prod mode. To override this, set
>
> ```
> play.filters.https.redirectEnabled = true.
> ```

Be warned, HSTS can break your site if you have ANY need for plaintext HTTP - for example a subdomain you have not moved to HTTPS yet (e.g. blog.example.com), or internal sites using the same domain (intranet.example.com). Please set this to a **LOW** `max-age` first and build it up when you prove it is not causing and issue, please **do not** use `includeSubDomains` initially and really, really **do not** include `preload` until you ready for this (personally I think very few sites should set this at all). I have [blogged about the dangers of switching these on when people do not fully understand these](https://www.tunetheweb.com/blog/dangerous-web-security-features/) and, without tying to offend you, if you're struggling just to switch these on then I'd definitely count you in that camp for now!

Comment: Then why did you accept the answer? Anyway, are you making this request over HTTPS or over HTTP?

Comment: OK because HSTS should not be sent over HTTP so thought it might be that. I'm running out of ideas. Based on the limited information you've given it should be working, but am running a bit blind here to be honest. What version of Playframework are you using? And anything in error logs? And are you connecting directly to Scala or via some other web server? Can you try connecting directly?

Comment: No HSTS is set on the HTTPS response only. Are you definitely connecting to the scala server using HTTPS? If not then that might explain why you are not seeing this Header this includes when connecting via proxy pass through Nginx - this proxy pass must be set to HTTPS. Also HSTS should be used in addition to a redirect (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37767031/301-redirect-and-hsts-in-htaccess/). Why have you blocked HTTP access? What purpose do you think that serves?

Comment: So over HTTP? I should not send the header over HTTP only over HTTPS.

Comment: Well I'm assuming that once you make the call via HTTPS that the header will start to populate. I'm guessing that the playframework is deliberately not including it over HTTP (as it should). But don't use the playframework so am guessing here. If you're asking how to enable HTTPS in the playframework then that is a different question and one I can't help you with unfortunately.

Comment: NOW only I found that Since I am using play version 2.3.6 and HSTS is not supported for that VERSION. Can you suggest me your ideas here? I can not upgrade my code to 2.6.x since there are many changes to be done.

Comment: It’s just a HTTP Header. If you have the ability to add those (either in play or nginx) then you can add HSTS. The protection for HSTS (and lots of other security headers) is at the client side and these don’t do anything on server side (except add the header to inform the client to enable it).